# I have a foreach loop and <li> and <ul> inside the foreach but i want to close the <ul/> tag outside the foreach

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

[this how it look when we debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK8wb.jpg) and
[this how we wanted to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzWqL.jpg)
i have a foreach loop and

and  inside the foreach but i want to close the  tag outside the foreach . so the opening of  inside and the closing outside.

```
    @foreach (var item1 in Model){
        if(num != item1.level){
           num = item1.level;
           <ul class="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.circleLevel)">
           @foreach (var item in Model){
              if(item1.level == item.level){
                 <li>
                    <a class="text" style="background-color: 
                     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsExest)" 
                     href="@Url.Action("Details", 
                     "Tree", new { id = item.User_ID 
                     })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
                 </li>
              }
            }
            <li>
                <div class="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
                title="add family member">@Html.ActionLink("+", "Create")</div>
            </li>


            <ul class="circle5"></ul>


        }
  }

</ul>
```

Comment: do you need two nested <ul>?

Comment: yes i need nested <ul>

Comment: add <li> tags around inner <ul>

Comment: can you show me how to do that please ?

Comment: your foreach for models doesnt seems like nested!

Comment: which foreach you talk about the first one ?

Comment: <li><ul class="circle5"></ul></li> but perhaps it would make more sense if you show what you want to actually display

Comment: If the closing </ul> is outside the for loop you could have multiple <ul>'s with only one </ul>

Comment: our problem with the first <ul> its inside foreach so we want the closing outside foreach  we want to show nested circles above each other when i put <ul/> inside the foreach circles become separated not above each other

Comment: show me a picture or sketch of what you want it to look like

Comment: not very clear what you want....

Comment: i added the photos of the output

Answer (score 0):

You can create the ul element outside the forloop and then append the `li` to the `ul` element.
Something like this:-

```
var createUlElem =  $('<ul class="ulClass"></ul>');
var liElem=''; 

$.each (items,function(indx,item1) {     
    liElem +='<li><a class="text">item1.name</a></li>';       
})


$(createUlElem).append($(liElem));
```

Comment: we want mvc c# not java script